# How to stop page reload when use beforeunload without confirmation popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault() 
});
```

Comment: You can't. The popup is always shown.

Comment: thanks @Rory McCrossan ..But it's possible to redirect onther page?

Comment: Within the `beforeunload` event? Also no. There is very little you can do within that event handler.

Comment: yes..within 'beforeunload',.if.not ,, so it's possible to when user refresh the page then redirect another page??
 .. in this case we use any jquey event

Comment: I don't understand what that means.

Comment: i mean when user refresh the page , then not reload current page but redirect another page

Comment: That would still rely on the `beforeunload` event, so it's still not possible.

Comment: it'is possible any other jquery event?.. not using 'beforeunload '.

Comment: Not using a plain event, no. You could concoct a solution using a flag in localStorage which you check for on successive reloads and then perform the redirect there.

Comment: yes, but there are reload the page  twice time,, first time is current page and second time is redirect another page ,, Right??

Comment: Yes. There is no other way to do what you ask, though. A better way would perhaps be to do it server side, but it depends on your implementation and goal.

Comment: ok ,thanks @Rory McCrossan

Comment: Ah, the days when you could stop someone closing the browser window - such fun for users:  close window, nope, close window, no chance, please close window, not gonna happen, close window, ok, here's 100 popups for pr0n with extremely explicit and very loud sound effects oh and I still didn't close that window.  Highly abused by spammers, advertisers (same thing?) and hijackers.  Be happy this is no longer possible.

Comment: Also sounds like an X/Y problem. For example doubly submitted forms which can be solved otherwise